# taking care of DB concurrency

Tags: database, jakarta-ee, concurrency, sum

Seems like  a common issue but I don't know a straight forward answer for it-

### environment

- Java EE environemnt (several JVMs)
- 2 phase commit setup
- Oracle DB

### given

DB table with 'AMOUNT' column

### logic

```
if SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) WHERE... + current amount < Const. ==> insert row
```

### problem

race condition - i would like to insert the row only when i do 'commit'. meanwhile, i dont want no other thread to access the data i used for my summation. i would also like to  reduce the non accessed db data as much as possible in order not to detain other threads.

### current solution

use of  Oracle's SELECT FOR UPDATE mechanism

---

Does anyone have other solutions for dealing with this problem? Out of the box solutions would be welcomed as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPA as part of Java EE provides [locking mechanisms](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkjiu.html).

In general there are pessimistic and optimistic locking.

**Pessimistic locking** in fact locks the table row  when data is read (the resulting SQL is a `SELECT FOR UPDATE ...` as your current solution), e.g.

```java
Person person = em.find(Person.class, personPK, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
```

**Optimistic locking** uses a version column for each table:

```java
public class Employee {
@ID int id;
@Version int version;
...
```

The pessimistic approach seems most suitable for your

Answer (score 0):

With Oracle, you may be able to use the `INSERT WHEN` clause (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9014.htm)) to do your conditional insert in one fell swoop on the database (using straight JDBC):

```
insert 
  when sumamount + ? < ? then
     into mytable (id, amount, otherfield) values(myseq.nextval, ?, ?)
  select sum(amount) sumamount from mytable
```

With the parameters:

- new amount
- constant
- new amount
- other field value

If that does not work out for you, then I would use a transaction manager with a "serializable" isolation level to prevent dirty, phantom or non-repeatable reads.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i think your first suggestion might not work since when performing the 'WHEN' clause, the used records in the SUM statement are not locked and hence the race condition is not prevented.